# Solving non-homogenous PDE with forcing function (which diappears!) dependent only on time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, eigenfunctions

Applying the method of eigenfunction expansion to the PDE
$$u_t -c^2u_{xx}=F(t)$$
$$0<x<L, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
$$u_x(0,t)u_x(L,t)=0$$

for the homogenous part of this equation ($L[v(x,t)]=0$) we get the following eigenvalues:
$$\lambda_n = \left( \frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)^2$$
and the following eigenfunctions:
$$X(x) = \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

We can now assume the following general solution:
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(t) \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

$$v(x,0) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n(0)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)=f(x)$$
Thus $$a_n(0)=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx$$

Differentiating and substituting to the original PDE, we get:
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left[ a_n'(t)+a(t)\left( \frac{n\pi}{L} \right)^2c^2 \right]\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)=F(t)$$

Now comes the most surprising part:

$$a_n'(t)+a(t)\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L} \right)^2=\frac{2}{L}F(t)\int\limits_{0}^L \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx = 0$$

Does this mean that $F(t)$ vanishes? I think it shouldn't be the case. Somehow I'm doing something correctly. Can someone please help me clarify this?

Comment: Only the last equation is false. One have to consider differently the case $n=0$ and the cases $n>0$. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left[ a_n'(t)+a(t)\left( \frac{n\pi}{L} \right)^2c^2 \right]\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)=F(t)$$

$$\implies \begin{cases}
a_n'(t)+a(t)\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L} \right)^2=0 \qquad n>0\\
a'_0(t)=F(t)
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
a_n(t)=A_n\exp \left(-\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L} \right)^2 t\right) \qquad n>0\\
a_0(t)=A_0+\int_0^t F(\tau)d\tau
\end{cases}$$

$$u(x,t)=A_0+\int_0^t F(\tau)d\tau +
\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \exp \left(-\left( \frac{n\pi c}{L} \right)^2 t\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

$$u(x,0)=A_0 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) = f(x)$$

This is the Fourier series of $f(x)$ which determines the coefficients $A_0\:,\:A_1\:,\: ...\:A_n\:,\: ...$.

Answer (score 1):

It vanishes except for $n=0$. In that situation $$a_0'(t) = F(t).$$

*saw that JJ beat me to it.*